# TFS 2012 Integration SharePoint 2013 Issue

Tags: sharepoint, tfs, sharepoint-2013

Trying to do integration between TFS and SharePoint, but running into some issues.

Followed instruction as below, with a small difference, TFS 2012 is sitting on one server, SharePoint 2013 is on a different server: http://blog.hinshelwood.com/integrate-sharepoint-2013-with-team-foundation-server-2012/

But when trying to add SharePoint Web Applications in TFS, TF255329 error popped up as below:

TF255329: The following site could not be accessed: `http://servername`. The server that you specified did not return the expected response. Either you have not installed the Team Foundation Server Extensions for SharePoint Products on this server, or a firewall is blocking access to the specified site or the SharePoint Central Administration site. For more information, see the Microsoft Web site (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=161206)

Is there any setups need to done in SharePoint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to run the TFS 2012 installer on the SharePoint server. The configuration wizard will appear, and there is an option to install the SharePoint Extensions for TFS after installation.

NOTE: If there are multiple web front ends, the SharePoint Extensions needs to be installed on each one.

Comment: en,interesting, so for the integration between two servers, both servers need to install TFS 2012 and SharePoint 2013. Is that the step need to be done first?

Comment: No, both servers do not need TFS 2012 and SharePoint 2013. The SharePoint server needs to have the SharePoint Extensions for TFS installed on its web front ends. These extensions are configured after installing TFS on the SharePoint server. This will not put the web services on the SharePoint server.

Comment: Thanks for that, install SharePoint Extensions for TFS helps, confused by the terminology, for me it's more like a TFS Extensions for SharePoint :)

Comment: In my case, TFS and SP is installed on the same machine. After that i can installed SP Extension and configured SP. But when i update the FQDN, getting the same error.

Comment: Using FQDN for the localhost, by default, is blocked. Here is more information on how to remove this behavior http://support.microsoft.com/kb/926642. Note that it says Server 2003, but I've seen it happen in all server versions after 2003.